# I'm getting trouble with react-native-vector-icons with autolink. It doesn't run anyhow

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

This is my problem.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'.
> Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\erick.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.71\descriptors\com.android.tools.build\gradle-api\3.3.1\fc7e8eef251519086b6ee9788cba4dd2\descriptor.bin

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this to see if there are any missing parts.

1. Edit `android/app/build.gradle`

```
    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

2. Edit `android/settings.gradle` to look like this (without the +):

```
    + include ':react-native-vector-icons'
    + project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

3. Edit `android/app/build.gradle` (note: app folder) to look like
   this:

```
    dependencies {
    + implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    }
```

4. Edit your `MainApplication.java` (deep in
   `android/app/src/main/java/...`) to look like this (note two places to
   edit):

```java
    package com.myapp;

    + import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

    ....

      @Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage()
    +   , new VectorIconsPackage()
        );
      }

    }
```

Comment: apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle" can i paste anywhere?

Comment: `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` Put under this code.

Comment: but what about iOs?

Answer (score 1):

in React Native > 0.60, you do not need to link packages manually. All you need is install your package and run link command. for react-native-vector-icons, remove any code and files you added to android or ios manually, or run `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`.

Remember that for ios, you need to get the last update of cocopods. if you have problem again, in ios folder run `pod install` command.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Look at the question. This is a problem that was created after link. And now this is happening in Android. It is not an iOS issue.

Comment: There is no difference in android or ios. in react native +0.60, you need to remove manual linking codes and react native will link packages automatically. try clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I mean, this problem was caused by trying to auto-link. This module has not been installed manually.

Comment: I didn't add any lib manually. Just via yarn. How can I unlink all deps manually?

Comment: @AliSn `RN >= 0.60` autolinking links all fonts. How to exclude unnecessary fonts?